# Firing a custom event in ExtJS 5.1

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have been trying to fire a custom event when a file has been successfully uploaded using a modal window. A grid on the main page listens for the event and should reload its store when a file is successfully uploaded. Problem is, the grid never catches this event.

I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how custom events work. What steps should I take to get back on track?

## SomeCommonUtilityClass.js

```
upload: function(args) {
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {

    /* form with some controls */
        buttons: [{
            text:'Upload',
            handler: function() {
                var win = this.up('window');
                var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                form.submit ({
                    url: myAjaxCall,
                    success: function() {
                        /* fire event here */
                        win.fireEvent('uploadSuccess');
                    },
                    failure: function() {
                        /*...*/
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 
    /* etc. */
    });
}
```

## SomeOtherFileView.js

```
{
    xtype:'grid',
    itemId:'uploadedGrid',
    listeners: {
        uploadSuccess: 'reloadUploadStore'
    },
    bind: {
        store:'{form}'
    },
    columns:[/*...*/]
}
```

## SomeOtherFileViewController.js

```
reloadUploadStore: function() {

    console.log("My event fired!") // Never gets here.
    /* .... */
    store.load({
        params: ({
            a: "a",
            b: "b"
        });
        callback: function() {
            /* do more stuff */
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are now listening to the event when fired from the grid, but you are firing the event from the window. You need to listen to the event from the window or define a scope.

Also you may consider to take a look at `Ext.callback`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SomeCommonUtilityClass**

```
win.fireEvent('uploadSuccess');
```

Example of custom event and Controller that listen on it:

**SomeOtherFileViewController**

```
init: function() {
        this.listen({
            // We are using Controller event domain here
            controller: {
                // This selector matches any originating Controller
                '*': {      
                    uploadSuccess: 'reloadUploadStore'
                }
            }
        });
    },
    reloadUploadStore: function() {
        //your code
    }
```

or if you want pass a argument:

```
win.fireEvent('uploadSuccess',extraArgument);
```

Controller code is the same. Only your function definition changes:

```
reloadUploadStore: function(yourArgument) {
    //Do your stuff with extraArgument
}
```